# Pull / Push in bootstrap 3.x.x grid system

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I have this grid order:

```
       <div class="row">   
            <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-6 col-xxs col-xs-pull-0">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Username ID</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="username_id" />
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-6 col-xxs">
                <label>Full Name</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="full_name" />
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-6 col-xxs">
                <label>Member Status</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="member_status" />
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-6 col-xxs">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Phone Number</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="phone_number_mobile" />
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-6 col-xxs">
                <label>Address / State</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="address_city_state" />
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-6 col-xxs">
                <label>Registered Date</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="dt_added" />
            </div>
        </div>
```

There was no problem of grid arrangement for `md` or `lg` but for `sm`... the result goes like these:

[image]

**JS Fiddle:**

https://jsfiddle.net/6bwmbL5y/

How I can rearrange back in balance? Any advice would be appreciate. Thanks!

Comment: Hint: always think "mobile first". Then rearrange the larger sizes.

Comment: Hi,

Do not forget than there is only 12 col in a row, in your code I can count 18 col. (more info here : http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_grid.asp )


Could you also furnish a fiddle of your work?

Thanks

Comment: Also, how do you want it to look at various sizes?

Comment: At large / medium it would be 4 divisions, but in sm/xs it would be 2 divisions

Comment: @DianeDuquesne I think, my DOM still right since the combination number of columns...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You had a slight mismatch of `form-group` elements. I've tidied them up and simplified the `col-*` classes too:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="form-group col-xs-6 col-md-3">
      <label>Username ID</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="username_id" />
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-xs-6 col-md-3">
      <label>Full Name</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="full_name" />
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-xs-6 col-md-3">
      <label>Member Status</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="member_status" />
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-xs-6 col-md-3">
      <label>Phone Number</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="phone_number_mobile" />
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-xs-6 col-md-3">
      <label>Address / State</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="address_city_state" />
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-xs-6 col-md-3">
      <label>Registered Date</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="dt_added" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: At `member status` why you did not add `form-group` class?

Comment: Because I forgot :) I've fixed it now.